# A positive word similar to envy

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, my friend goes skiing. I would also like to go skiing but am also very happy for him. So I do not envy him going skiing. Is there a single word to say "oh I am so happy you are going skiing but I would also love to go".

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Negative: *I **envied** [him] his new computer*. Positive: *I **admired** his new computer*.

Comment: [Envy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/envy) isn't always negative, perhaps OP is thinking of [jealousy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jealousy).

Comment: ...and in this case I would say the simple "I envy you" and not the tedious "I am so happy you are going skiing but I would also love to go". The tone of voice would show you aren't jealous, and the fact that you expressed it shows positivity, not the bottling up that often goes with jealousy.